# How to log error in Drupal 8 without specific module reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to write to error log on a Drupal 8 installation. I need to get the log for a specific condition to solve some errors that hit "core/install.php" drupal resource, due an unknown condition.

I noticed that in Drupal 8, I can use:

`\Drupal::logger('my_module')->error($message);`

The only fact I know, is that the following Drupal core php is executing:
[image: Code section where I want to add a new error log entryd]

**Given the fact that I don´t know the module´s name, how can I add an entry to error log (using \Drupal::logger or another alternative) ?**

**PD:** I´m not allowed to use watchdog dblog in my environment, so I need to log the error to error.log

Comment: Have you tried php's `error_log()` function?

Comment: On my drupal 8 installation error_log() doesn´t work.  My only option is to use \Drupal::logger

Answer (score 1):

I found that is mandatory to enable the "database logging" module in order to write logs.

After enable the Database Logging Module, I was able to see the log wrote by:

```
\Drupal::logger('log_example')->error($message);
```

Notice that 'log_example' could be any valid identifier, **not necessary a module name.**